# How to scrape text from tables with the same class attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape customer reviews on flights from airline quality.com and I'm running into a problem, as in the flights information all of the lines have the same 'review-value' class. I'm trying to solve it in the following way, usually all the comments have the same 4 flight description, except for the aircraft, which only appears in some. So, I did a if to determine that if there's no aircraft, then just append the next 'review-value', however, it's not working. Can you guys help me? The code can be found below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

myProxy = {
            "http"  : "http://10.120.118.49:8080",
            "https"  : "https://10.120.118.49:8080"
            }

headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

title_of_review=[]
details_about=[]
review_text=[]
type_of_traveller=[]
seat_type=[]
route_flown=[]
date_flown=[]
aircraft_flown=[]


url='https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/air-france/page/4/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100'

page1 = requests.get(url, proxies=myProxy, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.text, 'lxml')
page1.close()


for review in soup1.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "body"}):
    title=review.find('h2', attrs={'class': "text_header"})
    if title is not None:
        title_of_review.append(title.text)
    else:
        title_of_review.append('')

    details=review.find('h3', attrs={'class': "text_sub_header userStatusWrapper"})
    if details is not None:
        details_about.append(details.text)
    else:
        details_about.append('')

    texto=review.find('div', attrs={'class': "text_content"})
    if texto is not None:
        review_text.append(texto.text.strip('✅ Verified Review |').strip('\r\n\r\n'))
    else:
        review_text.append('')

    aircrafts=review.findAll('td', attrs={'class': "review-rating-header aircraft"})
    #print(aircrafts)
    all_reviews=review.findAll('td', attrs={'class': "review-value"})
    aircraft=all_reviews[0]
    if aircrafts is None:
        aircraft_flown.append('')        
    else:    
        aircraft_flown.append(aircraft.text)
```

Comment: I have a solution for you, but what do you want as an output? id your goal to get this into csv/table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse that table using pandas. The tricky part is the rating elements with multiple tags and attributes. But not to hard to remove the class "fill" and figure out the rating given. Here's a table of the output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

myProxy = {
            "http"  : "http://10.120.118.49:8080",
            "https"  : "https://10.120.118.49:8080"
            }

headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}


results_df = pd.DataFrame()
colsList = ['Aircraft', 'Type Of Traveller', 'Seat Type', 'Route', 'Date Flown', 
            'Seat Comfort', 'Cabin Staff Service', 'Food & Beverages', 
            'Inflight Entertainment', 'Ground Service', 'Value For Money,', 'Recommended']    
url='https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/air-france/page/4/?sortby=post_date%3ADesc&pagesize=100'

page1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.text, 'html.parser')
page1.close()

reviews = soup1.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "body"})
for review in reviews:
    for span in review.find_all("span", {'class':'star fill'}): 
        span.decompose()

    title=review.find('h2', attrs={'class': "text_header"})
    if title is not None:
        title_of_review = title.text.strip()
    else:
        title_of_review = ''

    details=review.find('h3', attrs={'class': "text_sub_header userStatusWrapper"})
    if details is not None:
        details_about = details.text.strip()
    else:
        details_about = ''

    texto=review.find('div', attrs={'class': "text_content"})
    if texto is not None:
        review_text = texto.text.strip('✅ Verified Review |').strip('\r\n\r\n')
    else:
        review_text = ''

    temp_df_alpha = pd.DataFrame([[title_of_review, details_about, review_text]], columns=['Title','Details','Text'])


    temp_df_beta = pd.read_html(str(review))[0].T
    new_header = list(temp_df_beta.iloc[0])
    temp_df_beta = temp_df_beta[1:]
    temp_df_beta.columns = new_header
    cols = [ col for col in new_header if col in colsList]
    temp_df_beta = temp_df_beta[cols]




    temp_df = temp_df_alpha.merge(temp_df_beta.reset_index(drop=True), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    rateCols = ['Seat Comfort', 'Cabin Staff Service', 'Food & Beverages', 
            'Inflight Entertainment', 'Ground Service', 'Value For Money']

    for col in rateCols:
        if col in temp_df.columns:
            try:    
                temp_df[col] = int(temp_df.iloc[0][col][0]) - 1
            except:
                temp_df[col] = 5


    results_df = results_df.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df.to_string())
                                              Title                                            Details                                               Text Type Of Traveller        Seat Type                                     Route      Date Flown  Seat Comfort  Cabin Staff Service  Food & Beverages  Inflight Entertainment  Ground Service Recommended                 Aircraft
0                          "I would fly them again"  1 reviews\n\n\n\nPeter-John de Kock (South Afr...  Trip Verified |  Cape Town to Los Angeles via ...          Business    Economy Class    Cape Town to Los Angeles via Paris CDG   December 2017           2.0                  3.0               3.0                     2.0             4.0         yes                      NaN
1               "service on board was just average"             Wenyu Zhao (France) 14th December 2017  Trip Verified | Flew Air France from Sydney to...      Solo Leisure    Economy Class          Sydney to Paris CDG via Shanghai     August 2017           3.0                  2.0               4.0                     3.0             2.0          no                      NaN
2                  "Enjoyed flying with Air France"      G Lamille (United Kingdom) 14th December 2017  Trip Verified |  Enjoyed flying with Air Franc...      Solo Leisure    Economy Class                        Paris to Vancouver    October 2017           5.0                  5.0               5.0                     5.0             4.0         yes         Boeing 777-200ER
3             "AF spreading this busline of theirs"       M Stanton (United States) 14th December 2017  Trip Verified |  Barcelona to Paris CDG. Ticke...          Business    Economy Class                    Barcelona to Paris CDG   December 2017           3.0                  3.0               1.0                     1.0             4.0          no                     A320
4                        "a good flying experience"  8 reviews\n\n\n\nS Lacey (United Kingdom) 12th...  Trip Verified | I had a pleasant flight with A...      Solo Leisure    Economy Class                      Hamburg to Paris CDG      March 2017           3.0                  4.0               4.0                     NaN             5.0         yes                A319/A320
5                   "horrible start to the holiday"    Luke Johnson (United Kingdom) 9th December 2017  Trip Verified | Flew Air France from London He...    Family Leisure    Economy Class    London Heathrow to Mauritius via Paris   December 2017           3.0                  3.0               2.0                     3.0             2.0          no                      NaN
6                      "it was Air France at fault"      Philip Jelovsek (Australia) 3rd December 2017  Trip Verified |  Paris to Abu Dhabi. My flight...      Solo Leisure    Economy Class                        Paris to Abu Dhabi   November 2017           NaN                  NaN               NaN                     NaN             1.0          no                      NaN
7         "not sure I will travel Air France again"  Luciana Queiroz (United States) 3rd December 2017  Trip Verified |  Nice to Paris. One person in ...    Family Leisure    Economy Class                             Nice to Paris   December 2017           1.0                  5.0               NaN                     NaN             1.0          no                      NaN
8                          "such a poor experience"       Francesco Lucchese (Italy) 2nd December 2017  Trip Verified | Bogota to Rome via Paris. It's...      Solo Leisure    Economy Class                  Bogota to Rome via Paris   November 2017           3.0                  1.0               3.0                     1.0             1.0          no                      NaN
9                        "Ridiculous and insulting"  25 reviews\n\n\n\nS Robinson (Austria) 1st Dec...  Trip Verified | Vienna - Paris CDG - London He...    Couple Leisure    Economy Class   Vienna to London Heathrow via Paris CDG   December 2016           4.0                  3.0               3.0                     NaN             1.0          no                      NaN
10             "experience very poor and stressful"          T Cody (United States) 25th November 2017  Trip Verified |  Air France accidentally cance...    Family Leisure    Economy Class            Barcelona to Atlanta via Paris    October 2017           1.0                  1.0               NaN                     NaN             1.0          no                      NaN
11                   "cabin staff were much better"  2 reviews\n\n\n\nSalal Bajwa (United Arab Emir...  Trip Verified |  London to Paris. Check in was...    Family Leisure    Economy Class                           London to Paris       June 2017           4.0                  5.0               4.0                     5.0             1.0         yes             Boeing 787-9
```